# A better way to access n-d array element with a 1-d index array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, grammar

Recently, I'm doing something about C++ pointers, I got this question when I want to access elements in multi-dimensional array with a 1-dimensional array which contains index.

Say I have a array `arr`, which is a 4-dimensional array with all elements set to `0` except for `arr[1][2][3][4]` is `1`, and a array `idx` which contains index in every dimension for `arr`, I can access this element by using `arr[idx[0]][idx[1]][idx[2]][idx[3]]`, or by using `*(*(*(*(arr + idx[0]) + idx[1]) + idx[2]) + idx[3])`.

The question comes with when `n` is large, this would be not so good, so I wonder if there is a better way to work with multi-dimensional accessing?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define N 10

int main()
{
    int arr[N][N][N][N] = {0};
    int idx[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    arr[1][2][3][4] = 1;
    cout<<"Expected: "<<arr[1][2][3][4]<<" at "<<&arr[1][2][3][4]<<endl;
    cout<<"Got with ****: ";
    cout<<*(*(*(*(arr + idx[0]) + idx[1]) + idx[2]) + idx[3])<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
Expected: 1 at 0x7fff54c61f28
Got with ****: 1
```

Comment: Choose which language you're interested in — the answer for C++ is probably different from the answer for C, unless you're going to do the un-C++-like thing and use raw arrays.  Since you've got a `using namespace std;` in the code, you're presumably interested in C++.

Comment: Yes, I' more interested how it works in C++.@JonathanLeffler

Comment: You might want to look at libraries that have already solved this problem, e.g. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: If you are interested in a C/CPP solution, use the C/CPP language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to solve this myself.

The idea is that use `void *` pointers, we know that every memory cell holds value or an address of a memory cell, so we can directly compute the offset of the target to the base address.

In this case, we use `void *p = arr` to get the base address of the n-d array, and then loop over the array `idx`, to calculate the offset.

For `arr[10][10][10][10]`, the offset between `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` is `10 * 10 * 10 * sizeof(int)`, since `arr` is 4-d, `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` is 3-d, so there is `10 * 10 * 10 = 1000` elements between `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`, after that, we should know that the offset between two `void *` adjacent addresses is `1 byte`, so we should multiply `sizeof(int)` to get the correct offset, according to this, we finally get the exact address of the memory cell we want to access.

Finally, we have to cast `void *` pointer to `int *` pointer and access the address to get the correct int value, that's it!

**With `void *`(not so good)**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define N 10

int main()
{
    int arr[N][N][N][N] = {0};
    int idx[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    arr[1][2][3][4] = 1;
    cout<<"Expected: "<<arr[1][2][3][4]<<" at "<<&arr[1][2][3][4]<<endl;
    cout<<"Got with ****: ";
    cout<<*(*(*(*(arr + idx[0]) + idx[1]) + idx[2]) + idx[3])<<endl;

    void *p = arr;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        p += idx[i] * int(pow(10, 3-i)) * sizeof(int);
    cout<<"Got with void *:";
    cout<<*((int*)p)<<" at "<<p<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Expected: 1 at 0x7fff5e3a3f18
Got with ****: 1
Got with void *:1 at 0x7fff5e3a3f18
```

*Notice:*
There is a warning when compiling it, but I choose to ignore it.

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:23:53: warning: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
         p += idx[i] * int(pow(10, 3-i)) * sizeof(int);
```

**Use `char *` instead of `void *`(better)**

Since we want to manipulate pointer byte by byte, it would be better to use `char *` to replace `void *`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define N 10

int main()
{
    int arr[N][N][N][N] = {0};
    int idx[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    arr[1][2][3][4] = 1;
    cout<<"Expected: "<<arr[1][2][3][4]<<" at "<<&arr[1][2][3][4]<<endl;

    char *p = (char *)arr;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        p += idx[i] * int(pow(10, 3-i)) * sizeof(int);
    cout<<"Got with char *:";
    cout<<*((int*)p)<<" at "<<(void *)p<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Expected: 1 at 0x7fff4ffd7f18
Got with char *:1 at 0x7fff4ffd7f18
```

**With `int *`(In this specific case)**

I have been told it's not a good practice for `void *` used in arithmetic, it would be better to use `int *`, so I cast `arr` into `int *` pointer and also replace `pow`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define N 10

int main()
{
    int arr[N][N][N][N] = {0};
    int idx[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    arr[1][2][3][4] = 1;
    cout<<"Expected: "<<arr[1][2][3][4]<<" at "<<&arr[1][2][3][4]<<endl;
    cout<<"Got with ****: ";
    cout<<*(*(*(*(arr + idx[0]) + idx[1]) + idx[2]) + idx[3])<<endl;
    int *p = (int *)arr;
    int offset = 1e3;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        p += idx[i] * offset;
        offset /= 10;
    }
    cout<<"Got with int *:";
    cout<<*p<<" at "<<p<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

*Output*

```
Expected: 1 at 0x7fff5eaf9f08
Got with ****: 1
Got with int *:1 at 0x7fff5eaf9f08
```

Comment: Note that you could have just used a 1-D array in the first place!

Comment: You should use `int *p` instead - it's not defined to do arithmetic on void pointers. Also, `pow` is a floating point function and therefore may introduce rounding errors

Comment: Yes, 1-D would be nice, but I need n-D array for some purpose. you mentioned that I should use `int *p`, like this `int *p = (int *)arr;for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)p += idx[i] * int(pow(10, 3-i));`? it sure helps, and I know there might be rounding errors with `pow`,maybe calculate it myself would be better?@M.M

Comment: As an aside, if you want to do arithmetic on byte addresses, you should use `char*`, not `void*`.

Comment: @Hurkyl that's what my previous comment was about!

Comment: @M.M: I agree that `int*` is better in this particular case, I just wanted to point out that `char*` is the right type for what the post was trying to do with void*` should he ever be in a situation where that *really is* what he wants to do.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes you're right, I should use `char *` instead of `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you constructor your algorithm for indexing a multi dimensional array will vary depending on the language of choice; you have tagged this question with both C and C++. I will stick with the latter since my answer would pertain to C++. For a little while now I've been working on something similar but different so this becomes an interesting question as I was building a multipurpose multidimensional matrix class template.

What I have discovered about higher levels of multi dimensional vectors and matrices is that the order of 3 repetitiously works miracles in understanding the nature of higher dimensions. Think of this in the geometrical perspective before considering the algorithmic software implementation side of it.

Mathematically speaking Let's consider the lowest dimension of 0 with the first shape that is a 0 Dimensional object. This happens to be any arbitrary point where this point can have an infinite amount of coordinate location properties. Points such as p0(0), p1(1), p2(2,2), p3(3,3,3),... pn(n,n,...n) where each of these objects point to a specific locale with the defined number of dimensional attributes. This means that there is no linear distance such as length, width, or height and conversely a magnitude in any direction or dimension where this shape or object that has no bounds of magnitude does not define any area, volume or higher dimensions of volume. Also with these 0 dimensional points there is no awareness of direction which also implies that there is no angle of rotation that defines magnitude. Another thing to consider is that any arbitrary point is also the zero vector. Another thing to help in understand this is by the use of algebraic polynomials such that `f(x) = mx+b` which is linear is a One Dimensional equation, shape(in this case a line) or graph, `f(x) = x^2` is Two Dimensional, `f(x) = x^3` is Three Dimensional, `f(x) = x^4` is Four Dimensional and so on up to `f(x) = x^n` where this would be N Dimensional. Length or Magnitude, Direction or Angle of Rotation, Area, Volume, and others can not be defined until you relate two distinct points to give you at least 1 line segment or vector with a specified direction. Once you have an implied direction you then have slope.

When looking at operations in mathematics the simplest is addition and it is nothing more than a linear translation and once you introduce addition you also introduce all other operations such as subtraction, multiplication, division, powers, and radicals; once you have multiplication and division you define rotation, angles of rotation, area, volume, rates of change, slope (also tangent function), which thus defines geometry and trigonometry which then also leads into integrations and derivatives. Yes, we have all had our math lessons but I think that this is important in to understanding how to construct the relationships of one order of magnitude to another, which then will help us to work through higher dimensional orders with ease once you know how to construct it. Once you can understand that even your higher orders of operations are nothing more than expansions of addition and subtraction you will begin to learn that their continuous operations are still linear in nature it is just that they expand into multiple dimensions.

Early I stated that the order of 3 repetitiously works miracles so let me explain my meaning. Since we perceive things on a daily basis in the perspective of 3D; we can only visualize 3 distinct vectors that are orthogonal to each other giving you our natural 3 Dimensions of Space such as Left & Right, Forward & Backward giving you the Horizontal axis and planes and Up & Down giving you the Vertical axis and planes. We can not visualize anything higher so dimensions of the order of `x^4, x^5, x^6 etc...` we can not visualize but yet they do exist. If we begin to look at the graphs of the mathematical polynomials we can begin to see a pattern between odd and even functions where `x^4, x^6, x^8` are similar where they are nothing more than expansions of `x^2` and functions of `x^5, x^7 & x^9` are nothing more than expansions of `x^3`. So I consider the first few dimensions as normal: Zero - Point, 1st - Linear, 2nd - Area, and 3rd - Volume and as for the 4th and higher dimensions I call all of them Volumetric.

So if you see me use Volume then it relates directly to the 3rd Dimension where if I refer to Volumetric it relates to any Dimension higher than the 3rd. Now lets consider a matrix such that you have seen in regular algebra where the common matrices are defined by `MxN`. Well this is a 2D flat matrix that has `M * N` elements and this matrix also has an area of `M * N` as well. Let's expand to a higher dimensional matrix such as `MxNxO` this is a 3D Matrix with `M * N * O` elements and now has `M * N * O` Volume. So when you visualize this think of the `MxN` 2D part as being a page to a book and the `O` components represents each page of a book or slice of a box. The elements of these matrices can be anything from a simple value, to an applied operation, to an equation, system of equations, sets or just an arbitrary object as in a storage container. So now when we have a matrix that is of the 4th order such as `MxNxOxP` this now has a 4th dimensional aspect but the easiest way to visualize this is that This would be a 1 dimensional array or vector to where all of its `P` elements would be a 3D Matrix of a Volume of `MxNxO`. When you have a matrix of `MxNxOxPxQ` now you have a 2D Area Matrix of `PxQ` where each of those elements are a `MxNxO` Volume Matrix. Then again if you have a `MxNxOxPxQxR` you now have a 6th dimensional matrix and this time you have a 3D Volume Matrix where each of the `PxQxR` elements are in fact 3D Matrices of `MxNxO`. And once you go higher and higher this patter repeats and merges again. So the order of how arbitrary matrices behave is that these dimensionalities repeat: 1D are Linear Vectors or Matrices, 2D are Area or Planar Matrices and 3D is Volume Matrices and any thing of a higher repeats this process compressing the previous step of Volumes thus the terminology of Volumetric Matrices. Take a Look at this table:

```
// Order of Magnitude And groupings     
-----------------------------------
Linear         Area          Volume
x^1            x^2           x^3
x^4            x^5           x^6
x^7            x^8           x^9
x^10           x^11          x^12
...            ...           ...
----------------------------------
```

Now it is just a matter of using a little bit of calculus to know which order of magnitude to index into which higher level of dimensionality. Once you know a specific dimension it is simple to take multiple derivatives to give you a linear expression; then traverse the space, then integrate to the same orders of the multiple derivatives to give the results. This should eliminate a good amount of intermediate work by at first ignoring the least significant lower dimensions in a high dimensional order. If you are working in something that has 12 dimensions you can assume that the first 3 dimensions that define the first set of volume is packed tight being an element to another 3D Volumetric Matrix and then once again that 2d order of Volumetric Matrix is itself an element of another 3D Volumetric Matrix. Thus we have a repeating pattern and now it's just a matter of apply this to construct an algorithm and once you have an algorithm; it should be quite easy to implement the methods in any programmable language. So you may have to have a 3 case switch to determine which algorithmic approach to use knowing the overall dimensionality of your matrix or n-d array where one handles orders of linearity, another to handle area, and the final to handle volumes and if they are 4th+ then the overall process becomes recursive in nature.